# Remove application icon and title from Honeycomb action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-3.0-honeycomb

How can I remove the application icon & title which comes by default in an action bar?

There is a similar question here: [Can i hide the App Icon from the Action Bar in Honeycomb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030700/can-i-hide-the-app-icon-from-the-action-bar-in-honeycomb), but it doesn't talk about how to do it?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Call [`setDisplayShowHomeEnabled()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayShowHomeEnabled%28boolean%29) and [`setDisplayShowTitleEnabled()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayShowTitleEnabled%28boolean%29) on `ActionBar`, which you get via a call to `getActionBar()`.

Comment: Any way to remove the icon through XML?

Comment: Just figured it out... you use abDisplayOptions and set your desired combination of useLogo, showHome, homeAsUp, showTitle, and showCustom.  I wanted just the title with no icon, so I did `<item name="abDisplayOptions">showTitle</item>`

Comment: @James tried your xml letter for letter and that did not work (obviously), so to save others finding the correct thing it's e.g. `<item name="android:displayOptions">useLogo|showHome|showTitle</item>`

Comment: @Cel I'm pretty sure it's because I used Action Bar Sherlock and you did not.  That's why the names are different, but otherwise the code is basically the same.  I should've used the standard action bar to cover the more general case.  Sorry!

Comment: yes it works perfectly but it also removes homeUpIndicatior from actionbar so if need HomeUpIcon and no need of logo icon then you can just set getActionBar.setIcon(R.color.transparent);

Answer (score 79):

If you want to do it the XML way, then define a style (XML file) in the **/res/values-v11/** folder with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:displayOptions"></item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

In your **AndroidManifest.xml** set the theme defined above for your activity:

```
<activity
    ...
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
    ...
</activity>
```

This will remove the icon and the title and only display the action items. If you just want the title to be displayed, the use:

```
<item name="android:displayOptions">showTitle</item>
```

Or just the application logo:

```
<item name="android:displayOptions">showHome</item>
```

Or both (default)

```
<item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|showTitle</item>
```

Other options are available too, like: showCustom, useLogo, homeAsUp

Comment: does this work with Action Bar sherlock? I am trying it but I cant get it to work.

Comment: this isnt working with me, it needs API 11 and I want to support earlier versions

Comment: To get it to work for API < 11 (AppCompat) simply repeat the repeat the `item` entries in the `style` blocks **without** "android:" in the `name`. This accesses the AppCompat attributes which need to be overridden for the new styles to work.

Comment: if you are displaying a logo instead of an icon (in the action bar), you want to use showHome|useLogo, if you only use "useLogo", it is not going to work. This is just an apart :)

Answer (score 15):

Try

```
getActionBar.setIcon(R.color.transparent);
```

Comment: Wouldn't that just hide (not remove) it?

Comment: Yes, that will hide it.

Comment: But is that the same as "removing it"? Typically, non-visible elements still take up space. But *removed* elements do not. So does the above actually achieve the same effect as the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5720773/104223).

Comment: Kind of. It does not take up any space.

Comment: UPDATE: You can also add a transparent PNG in the dimensions of the ActionBarSherlock Icons, that would make sure you have enough space to tap on the default Back button on top left.

Comment: Im getting an error message here - transparent is underlined.

Comment: You need to add the property - <color name="transparent">#00000000</color> in color

Comment: or just replace getActionBar.setIcon(R.color.transparent); with getActionBar.setIcon(android.R.color.transparent);

Answer (score 2):

This will help you:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        //the rest of your code...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
actionBar.setIcon(R.color.transparent);

actionBar.setTitle("");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in onCreate()

```
ActionBar actionbar=getSupportActionBar();
actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
actionbar.setIcon(android.R.color.transparent);
```

user android.R.color.transparent

Answer (score 0):

> Try this combination

```
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.color.transparent);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true)
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are looking to simply remove the entire actiobar, you can try the [hide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Removing) method for actionBars:

```
getActionbar().hide();
```