# How do I hide the action bar icon in Android using a theme?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-actionbar

While I do know that you can hide the icon in the action bar by using setDisplayUseLogoEnabled, this takes a while and will result in the icon flashing for a second. Is there a way to avoid this by using themes or any other solution?

Comment: Do you call the actionbar .show() after or before .setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false) ?

Comment: I posted a [solution][1] in another thread.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12095926/1239858

Answer (score 1):

assuming you're after a full screen view, try looking at the

`WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN`

flag in the Window class

Comment: FLAG_FULLSCREEN is for the status bar. Fredrik is talking about the action bar (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try using getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_USE_LOGO)