# Removing app icon and text from ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove application icon and title from Honeycomb action bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720715/remove-application-icon-and-title-from-honeycomb-action-bar)

can this be done to free up more space in the ActionBar? I am compiling against sdk 15

Comment: I guess it's answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720715/remove-application-icon-and-title-from-honeycomb-action-bar

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

Comment: This has plenty of info about the ActionBar API: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html