# ActionBarSherlock Actionbar Customization ?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I want to remove the back icon and the application icon from the Actionbar. I am using ActionBarSherlock. I have seen many applications that dont show an application icon or a back button ? Is this the best implementation ?

Kind Regards,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove application icon and title from Honeycomb action bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720715/remove-application-icon-and-title-from-honeycomb-action-bar)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think by "back" button you mean up button that is used to navigate up the application's structural hierarchy. Anyway hope this piece of code solves your problem if you don't want to keep the app icon on top.

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);   
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);  // if you want to show title on Actionbar
```

Answer (score 1):

the action bar doesn't have a back button since all android devices should include a back button in some way or another.

what you probably mean is the [up button](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Home) , which should go to the "home page" of the app.

you don't have to use it . it's just a nice thing to have. use `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled` for showing and hiding it .