# How to remove Application icon from Action Bar in Android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am using Action bar with Tabs. I want to hide app icon from action bar. I use the below code, but action bar is showing below Tabs. Both are not useful for me.

Any one help me!

```
 actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
```

and

```
 actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);` should do it.

Comment: Edited the answer. Can you try now?

Comment: I'm using `ActionBarSherlock`. Not sure if these methods are in standard `ActionBar`.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setIcon%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29

Comment: Yes..Am using standard Action Bar

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayUseLogoEnabled%28boolean%29

Comment: The methods are there. I checked the standard documentation. I've given the links.

Comment: But when trying to type the method "actionBar.setIcon()" showing error.

Comment: Which API version are you developing for?

Comment: Am using Android API 11..tab.setIcon() is available not for actionBar

Comment: Not sure, perhaps you could use setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true) and opt for a transparent image.

Answer (score 4):

add

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)
```

Comment: Thanks! I want title not icon.I used it..But both are invisible

Comment: try this answer -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720715/remove-application-icon-and-title-from-honeycomb-action-bar/12095926#12095926