# How can I find out similar texts / strings given a string?

Tags: database, algorithm

In sites like Quora or Stack Overflow, on a particular question, they are able to show questions that are possibly related. A quick look at them would reveal that they are merely looking for questions with similar text content. Is there any standard technique to find out such similar texts from a DB table where all texts are stored?

For example if you go to this question - 
[How to remove Application icon from Action Bar in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626216/how-to-remove-application-icon-from-action-bar-in-android)
it shows the following question as related - 
[Remove application icon and title from Honeycomb action bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720715/remove-application-icon-and-title-from-honeycomb-action-bar?rq=1) .

If I have column `questionText`, where the questions texts are stored, in a table `questions`, how will I find out such related strings?

Comment: It is called a "full text index".

Comment: Other used Sphinx (with MySQL) for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to extract keyword tokens from your documents and them find correlation between them. You can use a FOSS tool like [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/) to do that for you.

They can rely on tags also.