# Removing an icon from the Actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library

I want a custom ActionBar with Tabs that has a graphic background (displaying just one image) and 3 tabs.
I can't remove the icon of the actionbar.I've been through tens of stackoverflow questions about how to remove the icon and title, but nothing worked. 
I have a minSdk=14, ViewPager, ActionBar compat7, ActionBarActivity. Would any of these hinder it?

This is the code I have. Some declarations are excessive, I've been trying everything I could.
The best I got is an actionbar with no title, but the icon never goes away.

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);

actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false); // this hides the icon well but doesn't
                                          // work if you use actionbar tabs (viewpager)
```

solution below

Thanks

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720715/remove-application-icon-and-title-from-honeycomb-action-bar and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14606294/remove-icon-logo-from-action-bar-on-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is this:

((View)findViewById(android.R.id.home).getParent()).setVisibility(View.GONE);

as seen on: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/327#issuecomment-10593286

Using actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false) hides the icon, but your actionbar ends up being below the viewpager tabs (if you're using any)

Comment: ActionSherlock .. Was not recommended by JackeWharton ....http://jakewharton.com/deprecated-from-inception/

Comment: @ursgtm, I'm not using ActionBarSherlock. I'm using the Google Compat7 library. It seems that the issue exists natively as well as on sherlock...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried for `actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false)`

Comment: Yes, that does solve the problem actually but due to a bug or strange design, the tabs go above the actionbar (in case you're using a viewpager). Posting a workaround solution below