# How can i remove icon and title from ActionBar in Android on startup?

Tags: android

In my android project, I wish to disable icon and the title in ActionBar.

Here is the code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

But always on startup they appear and after a while they disappear but i don't want them at all. How can i remove them on startup?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove application icon and title from Honeycomb action bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720715/remove-application-icon-and-title-from-honeycomb-action-bar)

Comment: can you explain in more detail.

Comment: Just call those codes in _oncreate_ method instead of _onCreateOptionsMenu_

Comment: If you are new to SO please read 
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: i called them oncreate and still the same.

Comment: achilles. i preass run as android application and when i look at emulator the icon and tthe title appear, but after 2-3 seconds they disappear as i want. I dont wont them to appear at all. Not even for 1 second

Comment: @c_user89 try to customized your action bar using XML

Comment: if u don't want title bar then In `onCreate` add this Line `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`

Answer (score 0):

call `setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false)` and `setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)` on your ActionBar.

`actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);` should do it.

Or

For Splashscreen you should use this line in manifest and don't use getActionBar()

```
<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
```

and once when Splash Activity is finished in the main Activity use below or nothing

```
<item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
```

Reffer this ----> [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500283/how-to-hide-action-bar-before-activity-is-created-and-then-show-it-again)

Comment: i added <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="android:windowTitleSize">0dp</item> and it disappear. but if i want to reappear it during the main activity what should i do? those: getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    getActionBar().show(); dont help

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for that -

```
<activity android:name="YourActivityname" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
```

If you want the full screen of your device you can use below code -

```
<activity android:name="YourActivityname" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
```

And, also refer [Developer's Site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#theme)

**Another method**

Do this in your `onCreate()` method.

```
    //Remove title bar
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    //Remove notification bar
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

   //set content view AFTER ABOVE sequence (to avoid crash)
    this.setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_name_here);
```

`this` refers to the `Activity`.

Comment: i tried the second method you told me and the same thing.i added <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item> <item name="android:windowTitleSize">0dp</item> and i got what i wanted but i have now trouble reappearing the actionbar.this: getActionBar().show();  doesnt help

Comment: Make sure the `setContentView(view)` has been already called for your Activity, otherwise `getActionBar()` will return null.

Comment: also check that `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" />` is there in the manifest

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25972954/437039) can help you. It helped me.

`<quote>`
Best method is to set the display options to `useLogo` in your theme. E.g.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:displayOptions">useLogo</item>
</style>
```

This won't actually show the logo (if set) because `showHome` is not included.
`</quote>`

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

**NOTE:** The `getActionBar()` method was added in Honeycomb (API: 11) and later

Comment: it still appears for the first 2-3 seconds

Comment: change `setContentView` position and try again